# C++ string to floating point precision?

Tags: c++, string, floating-point, precision

I have a question regarding floating point precision.
I know that you can set precision of floating point number using `setprecision(p)` where `p` is the precision you can choose. But I only know to use this in `cout` format. What I want to do is, given a string `s`:

```
string s = "-9.77287190e+01";
float f = atof(s.c_str());
```

Is there a way to make the float variable f to hold the value with correct precision when changing from a string to float?

Comment: You can reduce the effect with a `double`, but a `float` is only good to about 7 digits.

Comment: setprecision doesn't change the precision of a floating point number.  floating point precision is set in your hardware.  It simply changes how it is printed out.

Comment: If the input number is not representable in [float precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) (or double if you switch as mentioned before), there will be no way to make an exact conversion.